# Django many to many relation on generic models

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have some models which will need to have many to many relation with some images. Instead of creating each relation individually, I want to have some generic model relations that I can use for all my models. So I've created Image and ImageItem models (I'm not sure if I'm on the right track..):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

class ImageItem(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

What I want to do is, every time I create a new image, I want to select which objects I want to assign this image to. So into the admin I need to have something like:

```
Image: chicago_bulls.jpg
Selected model: Player
Selected:
Michael Jordan
Scotie Pippen
```

or

```
Image: kobe_bryant.jpg
Selected model: Team
Selected:
Los Angeles Lakers
US National Team
```

Is my model design correct? I also want to use ModelMultipleChoiceField for that but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs explaining the [`GenericInlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline).

If i get you right, the example does exactly what you want:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

It's a bit different from your design, as the image field is part of model that adds generic relations to all kind of other (content) objects/models.

That way you can simply attach images via the admin interface using the already mentioned `InlineAdmins`:

```
class ImageInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = Image

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ImageInline,
    ]
```

Comment: Hi arie. Thank you for your response. Basically I'm trying to set product images from the Image admin page. 1) Select image 2) Choose teams or players to add that image to. Sorry, it's a bit confusing and a bit non-standard I guess.

Comment: So what's wrong about the standard rendering of the GenericForeignKey in Django's admin? Take a look at this detailed explanation: http://blog.yawd.eu/2011/admin-site-widget-generic-relations-django/ Sure you could add some javascript to make the widget more usable, but for a start it should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Seems like there is no easy way of doing this.